# Numpy: multiplying matrix elements with array of matrices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

I need to multiply the elements of a, let's say, 2x2 matrix, x, with a matrix, y, whose elements are 2x2 matrices. When I use the conventional numpy multiplication it takes the entire matrix, x, and multiples it with each matrix in y. I have been searching the numpy doc. for something that will replicate this:

```
>>> x = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]])
>>> x
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 1]])
>>> y = np.ones((2, 2, 2, 2))
>>> y
array([[[[ 1.,  1.],
         [ 1.,  1.]],
    [[ 1.,  1.],
     [ 1.,  1.]]],
   [[[ 1.,  1.],
     [ 1.,  1.]],
    [[ 1.,  1.],
     [ 1.,  1.]]]])
>>> multiply(x,y)
[[[[1, 1],
   [1, 1]],
  [[0, 0],
   [0, 0]]],
 [[[0, 0],
   [0, 0]],
  [[1, 1],
   [1, 1]]]]
```

Comment: what is exactly your question?

Comment: How do I multiply each element of matrix x as if it were a scalar with the corresponding matrix in y. basically I need something that will replicate the multiply function that I gave in the example code.

Comment: @user2909415 It seems you are looking for `np.tensordot(x, y, axes=[[0, 1], [0, 1]])`, but your question is unclear... what is the expected result?

Comment: @SaulloCastro A better explanation might be that I want the element at (1, 1) in x to multiply with the element (1, 1) in y except difficulty here is that that element in y is a 2x2 matrix so I need it to multiply the element in x as a scalar with that 2x2 matrix in y. I tried your example and got a ValueError: shape-mismatch for sum
.

Comment: Ones and zeros make for confusing examples for multiplication since is `1`: just `1`, or maybe `1*1`, or maybe `1*1 + 0*1`, etc..

Comment: @user2909415 do you want to use a written function in `numpy` or `scipy` or any kind of answer would be enough for you?

Comment: @Dalek Well what really matters in this situation is speed. I wanted a numpy/scipy solution since I assume that would be faster than manually retrieving each value in x and multiplying it with the corresponding matrix in y (for which yes I know how to do). But if you have an efficient solution then I would love to see it.

Comment: @user2909415 I reckon Saullo's answer is satisfying your requirement, isn't it?

Comment: @ Yes it does. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: From the comments of @Dalek and @DSM it seems that actually what you want is:

```
np.einsum('ij, ijkl-> ijkl', x, y)
```

Comment: I think he/she is looking for a way to multiply each element of matrix `x` in each element of matrix `y`, which is a `2x2` matrix, the example of the requested answer is given in the question.

Comment: IIUC the einsum version of what the OP is looking for is `np.einsum('ij,ijkl->ijkl', x, y)`.  I haven't had my coffee yet though.